# Error converting value to List<string> from dynamic data

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

I have error when i am trying ti convert dynamic data that have structure

> "["myvalue1","myvalue2"]"

to  List

My function that send request to service

```
        List<string> SFRecipients = new List<string>();
        SFRecipients.Add("myvalue1");
        SFRecipients.Add("myvalue2");


        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jSFRecipients = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(SFRecipients);
        uri = "http://testservices.com/Send";
        client = new RestClient(uri);
        request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("SFRecipients", jSFRecipients);
        response = client.Execute(request);
```

Service function

```
public void Send(JObject data)
        {
        dynamic Mydata= data;
       //Mydata.SFRecipients is = ["myvalue1","myvalue2"]
       // i have debuged
       List<string> Recipients = Mydata.SFRecipients.ToObject<List<string>>();
```

And then i get error

**Error converting value "["myvalue1","myvalue2"]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path ''.**

What i am missing here?

Comment: Is there any inner exception? Also, check that you actually don't have these trailing double quotes in your string. JSON array cannot start from `"`.